# SQL three tables to return one row

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

Hey people sorry if this question isnt really clean but it goes as following

i have a homework quest which goes along the lines of this.
Write a quer to return how many subjects this student takes with the LastName "Field"

the three tables are:

```
Students:
     StudentID
     FirstName
     LastName

StudentCourses:
      StudentCourseID
      StudentID
      CourseID

Courses:
      Maths
      Science
      English
      P.E
      Drama
      Film Studies
```

I have something like

```
SELECT Students.studentID, 
       Students.Lastname, 
       Students.CourseID 
  FROM Students 
 WHERE Students.LastName = "Field"
 INNER JOIN StudentCourses 
    ON Student.CourseID = StudentCourses.CourseID
  FULL JOIN Student 
    ON Student.RoleID = Courses.CourseID
```

This is written so i cannot test it but does this seem correct to anyone?

Comment: Nope, look at where `WHERE` is permitted; also, does nothing to count (_hint hint_) "how many"...and references a table that does not exist.

Comment: you almost certainly don't want a FULL JOIN. And what is "Student" table? Not the same as "Students"? It's not mentioned in your question. And why join a field "RoleID" to "CourseID". They don't seem to match, either

Comment: The `mysql` and `tsql` tags are, as a rule, incompatible. Do you require a solution that works for all manner of SQL dialects?

Answer (score 2):

Use COUNT() function to find the number of courses the student takes and use WHERE clause to filter the student’s last name as ‘Field’.

```
SELECT s.StudentID, s.LastName, COUNT(sc.CourseID)
FROM Students s 
JOIN StudentCourses sc 
ON s.StudentID = sc.StudentID 
WHERE  s.LastName = 'Field’;
```

Answer (score 1):

Where should come last. You don't really need the 3rd join to the courses table because you aren't selecting anything from it.

```
SELECT st.STUDENTID, 
       st.LASTNAME, 
       count(stc.COURSEID) as COURSECOUNT
FROM   STUDENTS st 
       INNER JOIN STUDENTCOURSES stc 
               ON st.COURSEID = stc.COURSEID 
WHERE  st.LASTNAME = 'Field'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query. `WHERE` clause should be after `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses

```
SELECT s.studentid,
       s.lastname,
       COUNT(sc.courseid)
  FROM student s
  JOIN studentcourses sc
    ON s.studentid = sc.studentid
 WHERE s.lastname = 'Field'
```