# T-SQL query to return row with no connected Users

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

Using a T-SQL return CourseName of a course with no students in it.

```
StudentCourses:

    StudentCourseID
    StudentID
    CourseID



Courses:

    CourseID
    CourseName
```

I have to find what CourseName has no students in it.
Maybe my brain is fried because I don't know where to begin.
Would I need a Left Join for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question shows zero effort, therefore I am downvoting it.

Comment: Your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46595467/sql-three-tables-to-return-one-row) mentioned homework (as well as different dbms). If you don't try, you won't learn.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `not exists` operator would probably be the easiest way of doing this:

```
SELECT coursename
FROM   course c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   studentcourses s
                   WHERE  s.courseid = c.courseid)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `LEFT JOIN` - it will return all courses and the corresponding students. Using `WHERE` clause we are filtering only this courses which do not have students:

```
SELECT coursename
FROM  course c
LEFT JOIN studentcourses  sc
    ON c.courseid = sc.courseid
WHERE sc.courseid IS NULL;
```